# element.all always returning count as 0

Tags: protractor

I am trying to test a dynamic web table using protractor and trying to find the count of headers, rows and cols but always getting 0 as the count
var x = element.all(by.xpath('//table//thead//tr//th'))

x.count().then(function(c){

console.log(c);

});

I tried using element.all(by.css ) as well and it returns the same , can anyone help?
I  used selenium and able to retrieve the value, so xpath is not wrong, but I have to use protractor to fetch the same.
Selenium script which is working
List  col = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='table-wrapper']//table//thead//tr/th"));
       System.out.println(col.size());

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrRRm.png)

Comment: if you know there is going to be at least one, you'll need to browser.wait for the presence of x.first(). Otherwise it is taking count too soon. Or you could add sleep, but that is gross. Or use async and x = await element.all... console.log (await x.count)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
var x = await element.all(by.css('table[title="status"]'))
//Add wait if the table take more time to load
x.count().then(function(c){
console.log(c);
});
```

Comment: Thanks the first one worked await did not, as a next step my scenario is to automate a dynamic table...the table has 3 columns always but the number of rows varies.(age range depends on selection) The values corresponding to each age range for Admitted and Discharged status have to be compared to backend( I have to compare the web element with o/p of a query to see if all works fine on ui). The challenge is how will I identify which query to call as this is dynamic..Say if only age  18-40 is present that will be my cell(0), so cell(1) and cell(2) should match the queries from db...

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should avoid `xpath` since it's very inefficient.

This should work for you:

```
var table = element(by.css('table.table'));

table
 .element(by.css('thead'))
 .all(by.css('tr th'))
 .count()
 .then(function(count) {
   console.log('count:',count);
 });
```